# Are questions asking where to post or find jobs on-topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/7731/where-do-computer-graphic-engineers-look-for-job-ads) has been up for a few days. It is asking for references to off-site resources for where to post job ads. It has 2 answers and 1 close vote. This seems to run afoul of the "no offsite resources questions" rule on "what can I ask", but people are answering it anyway. Have I misunderstood the rule, or is this off-topic?

Comment: It's up to the community to decide what is off-topic. I'm very interested to see what answers we get here and will act accordingly.